# Parsing DataStage log into C# object

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, datastage

I am trying to figure out an optimal way to parse the following DataStage job log into a C# object:

```
Event Id: 827
Time    : Mon Nov 14 12:29:35 2022
Type    : STARTED
User    : dsusr
Message Id      : IIS-DSTAGE-RUN-I-0070
Invocation Id   : RANDMONINVOCATIONID
Message :
        Starting Job DS_JOB_NAME.RANDMONINVOCATIONID.
        PS_APPL_Folders = (As pre-defined)
        PS_APPL_Folders.DIR_DATA = /data     (Compiled-in default)
        PS_APPL_Folders.DIR_DATA_IN = files/inputfiles     (Compiled-in default)
        PS_APPL_Folders.DIR_ERR = files/errorfiles     (Compiled-in default)
        PS_APPL_Folders.DIR_REJ = files/rejectfiles     (Compiled-in default)
        PM_FLOW_ID = 0
        $LKP_CUSTOM_ERR_JB_NM = JP_Lookup_Custom_Error
        DSJobController = SQ_Start_Job.RANDMONINVOCATIONID
Event Id: 828
Time    : Mon Nov 14 12:29:35 2022
Type    : INFO
User    : dsusr
Message Id      : IIS-DSTAGE-RUN-I-0126
Invocation Id   : RANDMONINVOCATIONID
Message :
        Environment variable settings:
        _=/usr/bin/nohup
        TDG_STR_StrMin_Length=1
        TDG_STR_StrNewLines=false
        TDG_STR_StrSpaces=false
        TDG_STR_StrSpecial=false
        TDG_STR_StrUpperCase=true
        TDG_TBL_Type=standard
        TDG_Username=fu_uq47ep
        TDG_UserPassword=********
        TDG_UserStory_No=STRY02TEST
Event Id: 829
Time    : Mon Nov 14 12:29:35 2022
Type    : INFO
User    : dsusr
Message Id      : IIS-DSTAGE-RUN-E-0268
Invocation Id   : RANDMONINVOCATIONID
Message :
        DS_JOB_NAME.RANDMONINVOCATIONID: Set NLS locale to US-ENGLISH,US-ENGLISH,US-ENGLISH,US-ENGLISH,US-ENGLISH
Event Id: 830
Time    : Mon Nov 14 12:29:35 2022
Type    : INFO
User    : dsusr
Message Id      : IIS-DSTAGE-RUN-I-0019
Invocation Id   : RANDMONINVOCATIONID
Message :
        DS_JOB_NAME.RANDMONINVOCATIONID.JobControl (@Coordinator): Starting new run of checkpointed Sequence job
Event Id: 831
Time    : Mon Nov 14 12:29:37 2022
Type    : BATCH
User    : dsusr
Message Id      : IIS-DSTAGE-RUN-I-0034
Invocation Id   : RANDMONINVOCATIONID
Message :
        DS_JOB_NAME.RANDMONINVOCATIONID -> _FR_JP_TEST_JOB_CC.RANDMONINVOCATIONID): Job run requested
        Mode (row/warn limits) = 0/0
        Generating operational metadata
        Job Parameters --->
        PM_FLOW_ID=0
        PS_Database=(As pre-defined)
        PS_Folders=(As pre-defined)
        PS_Database=(As pre-defined)
        PS_CustomErrors=(As pre-defined)
        PS_APPL_Folders=(As pre-defined)
        PM_JOB_RUN_ID=123752
        PM_MASTER_SEQUENCE_NM=DS_JOB_NAME
RANDMONINVOCATIONIDDCA8689FE4A3BB45C63E4361AAD61
        $LKP_CUSTOM_ERR_JB_NM=JP_Lookup_Custom_Error
        DSJobController=DS_JOB_NAME.RANDMONINVOCATIONID
Event Id: 832
Time    : Mon Nov 14 12:29:37 2022
Type    : INFO
User    : dsusr
Message Id      : IIS-DSTAGE-RUN-I-0019
Invocation Id   : RANDMONINVOCATIONID
Message :
        DS_JOB_NAME.RANDMONINVOCATIONID.JobControl (DSRunJob): Waiting for job_FR_JP_TEST_JOB_CC.RANDMONINVOCATIONID to start
Event Id: 833
Time    : Mon Nov 14 12:29:38 2022
Type    : INFO
User    : dsusr
Message Id      : IIS-DSTAGE-RUN-I-0019
Invocation Id   : RANDMONINVOCATIONID
Message :
        DS_JOB_NAME.RANDMONINVOCATIONID.JobControl (DSWaitForJob): Waiting for job_FR_JP_TEST_JOB_CC.RANDMONINVOCATIONID to finish
Event Id: 834
Time    : Mon Nov 14 12:29:45 2022
Type    : INFO
User    : dsusr
Message Id      : IIS-DSTAGE-RUN-I-0019
Invocation Id   : RANDMONINVOCATIONID
Message :
        DS_JOB_NAME.RANDMONINVOCATIONID.JobControl (DSWaitForJob): Job_FR_JP_TEST_JOB_CC.RANDMONINVOCATIONID has finished, status = 1 (Finished OK)
Event Id: 835
Time    : Mon Nov 14 12:29:45 2022
Type    : INFO
User    : dsusr
Message Id      : IIS-DSTAGE-RUN-I-0019
Invocation Id   : RANDMONINVOCATIONID
Message :
        DS_JOB_NAME.RANDMONINVOCATIONID.JobControl (@XJS_FR_JP_TEST_JOB_CC): Checkpointed run of job _FR_JP_TEST_JOB_CC.RANDMONINVOCATIONID'
Event Id: 836
Time    : Mon Nov 14 12:29:45 2022
Type    : INFO
User    : dsusr
Message Id      : IIS-DSTAGE-RUN-I-0019
Invocation Id   : RANDMONINVOCATIONID
Message :
        DS_JOB_NAME.RANDMONINVOCATIONID.JobControl (@Coordinator): Removed checkpoint record at successful completion of sequence
Event Id: 837
Time    : Mon Nov 14 12:29:45 2022
Type    : INFO
User    : dsusr
Message Id      : IIS-DSTAGE-RUN-I-0019
Invocation Id   : RANDMONINVOCATIONID
Message :
        DS_JOB_NAME.RANDMONINVOCATIONID.JobControl (@Coordinator): Summary of sequence run
        12:29:35: Sequence started (checkpointing on)
        12:29:36: XJS_FR_JP_TEST_JOB_CC (JOB_FR_JP_TEST_JOB_CC.RANDMONINVOCATIONID) started
        12:29:45: XJS_FR_JP_TEST_JOB_CC (JOB_FR_JP_TEST_JOB_CC.RANDMONINVOCATIONID) finished, status=1 [Finished OK]
        12:29:45: Sequence finished OK
Event Id: 838
Time    : Mon Nov 14 12:29:45 2022
Type    : STARTED
User    : dsusr
Message Id      : IIS-DSTAGE-RUN-I-0077
Invocation Id   : RANDMONINVOCATIONID
Message :
        Finished Job DS_JOB_NAME.RANDMONINVOCATIONID.
```

I've defined the following class:

```
public class JobLog
{
        public int EventId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string MessageId { get; set; }
        public string InvocationId { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I was thinking to split the log by `\r\n` and check if the line contains the word `Event Id` then assign the value to the `EventId` property, and so on.
My problem is with the message property, since it can include multiple lines. How should the logic be here?

```
    private void ParseLog()
    {
            var log = GetSampleLog()
                    .Split("\r\n");

            foreach (var line in log)
            {
                    if (line.Contains("Event Id:", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                            var logObj = new JobLog
                            {
                                    EventId = int.Parse(line.Split(":")[1])
                            };
                    }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication51
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string line = "";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);

            List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
            Event _event = null;
            string[] splitArray = null;
            Boolean getMessages = false;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith("Event Id"))
                    {
                        splitArray = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                        _event = new Event();
                        events.Add(_event);
                        _event.eventID = splitArray[1].Trim();
                        getMessages = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (line.StartsWith("Time"))
                    {
                        int startOfDate = line.IndexOf(":") + 6;
                        string date = line.Substring(startOfDate).Trim();
                        _event.date = DateTime.ParseExact(date,"MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (line.StartsWith("Type"))
                    {
                        splitArray = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                        _event.type = splitArray[1].Trim();
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (line.StartsWith("User"))
                    {
                        splitArray = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                        _event.user = splitArray[1].Trim();
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (line.StartsWith("Message Id"))
                    {
                        splitArray = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                        _event.messageID = splitArray[1].Trim();
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (line.StartsWith("Invocation Id"))
                    {
                        splitArray = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                        _event.InvocationID = splitArray[1].Trim();
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(line.StartsWith("Message"))
                    {
                        getMessages = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (getMessages)
                    {
                        if(_event.messages == null)
                           _event.messages = new List<string>();
                        _event.messages.Add(line.Trim());

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class Event
    {
        public string eventID { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string user { get; set; }
        public string messageID { get; set; }
        public string InvocationID { get; set; }
        public List<string> messages { get; set; }
    }
 
}
```